# How to verify that my terminal's postgres connection is to the same data as Intellij?

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea

I am using intellij with postgres, and highlight sql commands to run them.

I also have postgres running in my terminal, and **I am getting different results from the same query when run in intellij vs. when run in the terminal.**

Here is the command run from Intellij:
[image]

The result shows one entry present:

[image]

However, running the same command in the terminal shows no table entries present.

[image]

Intellij and the terminal are connecting to the same database and port as shown by Intellij's connection settings

[image]

and by the result of `\conninfo` run in the terminal.

[image]

Furthermore, the schema matches as shown by Intellij's connection settings (shown above) and by the result of the terminal's `\d+ visitor_sign_in` command

[image]

**Why does this same command give different results when run in Intellij vs. when run in the terminal?**

Comment: Are you sure that you are selecting from the same database and schema in both cases?  Is there only one `visitor_sign_in` table?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen they are using the same database 'daratest', and also the same schema 'public'. I have edited the question adding the output of the terminal command '\d+ visitor_sign_in' to show that the schemas match.

Comment: Are you inside a transaction in either connection?

Comment: @jmelesky no not running inside a transaction in either.

Comment: Are you certain? Many libraries connect with `autocommit` turned off, and if it's turned off, you're in a transaction by default. Transactions could explain the difference in visible data.

Comment: I restarted Intellij, then reran my query and got no table entries. Then I ran my insert command (from intellij). After this insert command the table entry showed up when run in intellij. Still not when run in the terminal.

Comment: @jmelesky yes I am running with autocommit turned off.

Comment: But after running my insert command, intellij's commit button is still greyed out.

Comment: I wonder if this is an Intellij bug.

Comment: Query `pg_stat_activity` after the insert; if IntelliJ has left a transaction open, its session's `state` column should say `idle in transaction`.

Comment: @NickBarnes yes running `select * from pg_stat_activity;` does show 'idle in transaction'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your most recent comment ("yes running `select * from pg_stat_activity;` does show 'idle in transaction'."), here is what I believe is happening.

You have two connections, A and B.

A starts a transaction, inserts data, and then selects from that table. The table shows data (the data that was just inserted).

B connects, and selects from the same table. Since A has not committed, B does not see that data. In order for the data inserted by A to be visible to any other connections, you need A to commit its transaction.

Now, I don't know why IntelliJ is not offering you the opportunity to commit your transaction, but that lack of commit is the cause of your visibility problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this explanation is indeed consistent with the results that I am getting. The problem seems to be intellij not permitting me to commit, leaving the commit button grayed out. When I phrase my insert as an 'INSERT' statement instead of 'SELECT' calling an INSERT function, Intellij does ungray and give me the option to commit. So the problem seems to be Intellij not recognizing that I have made a change warranting a commit via a SELECT statement.